# How to synthetize a controller $\dot{u} = F x + G u$ which stabilizes $\dot{x} = Ax + Bu$?

Tags: control-theory

$\textbf{Introduction}$: I study linear control theory. Among strategies, we begin with vector field $Ax + Bu$, $A \in M_{n^2}(\mathbb{R})$, $B \in M_{n \times m}(\mathbb{R})$, and synthesize a controller $u$ given by product $F x$ such that matrix $A+BF$ has all eigenvalues on the left complex plane. For that, take a look at a brief explanation I write on [1] at the end of this post.

$\textbf{Explanation}$: My supervisor asked me if I could stabilize the same linear system with dynamic feedback $\dot{u}$ of kind $Fx + Gu$ i.e. synthesize matrices $F$ and $G$. My progress so far is to recognize matrix $\bar{A} = \begin{bmatrix} A & B \\ F & G\end{bmatrix}$ needs to have eigenvalues on the left complex plane OR there are positive symmetric matrices $\bar{P}$ and $\bar{Q}$ such that we satisfy equality $\bar{A}^\intercal \bar{P} + \bar{P} \bar{A} = -\bar{Q}$. He suggested finding such matrix $\bar{P}$, since it may be possible to extend to nonlinear systems.

$\textbf{Question}$: How to synthesize matrices $F$ and $G$ to stabilize linear system $\begin{bmatrix} \dot{x} \\ \dot{u} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} A & B \\ F & G\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ u \end{bmatrix}$

$\textbf{Appendix}$ Hello :). This is a summary of feedback stabilization $F x$. Matrix $F$ is given by formula $-P V^{-1}$, such that matrix P represents $n$ vectorial degrees of freedom for eigenvectors to follow and matrix of eigenvectors $V$ has column $v_i$ given as product $(\lambda_i I_n - A)^{-1} \, B \, p_i$, for eigenvalue $\lambda_i \not \in \lambda(A)$, or respective eigenvector associated to eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ i.e. it satisfies equality $(\lambda_i I - A) v_i = 0$. There are other corner cases such as not-controllable eigenvalues i.e. not-shiftable, whose eigenvectors $v_i$ and parameter $p_i$ are still related by the formula $(\lambda_i I - A) v_i - B p_i$, we conclude vector $p_i$ is 0, eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ must be on the left complex plane

Comment: If the system is not stabilizable (by a static state feedback controller), then, there is no dynamic controller exists that can stabilize the system.

Comment: @obareey do you have any place where I can have proof of your statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a beginning of an answer to put you on the right track. I can complete based on the comments.

First of all, you can observe that

$$
\begin{bmatrix} A & B \\ F & G\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} A & B \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ I\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} F & G\end{bmatrix}.
$$

It does look like a state-feedback control law right? The controllability matrix is given by

$$
\mathcal{C}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & B & AB & \ldots\\I_m & 0 &0 & \ldots\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Can you show that the pair $(A,B)$ is controllable if and only if the pair $$\left(\begin{bmatrix} A & B \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ I\end{bmatrix}\right)$$ is? Is it advantageous to consider the dynamic state-feedback control law for stabilization only?

Also, note that you can pick $\dot{u}=-\epsilon^{-1}(u-Fx)$. What happens when $\epsilon$ is very small? Have you heard of singular perturbation theory?

If you are not familiar with singular perturbation theory, it does not matter. The idea is if $\epsilon$ is very small, then we have that  $\epsilon\dot{u}\approx 0$ and, as a result, $u-Fx\approx0$, and we recover the original state-feedback control law. This can be made rigorous. The book by Khalil has a chapter on the topic.

Comment: Typo: the first plus sign on your equation is an equal sign

Comment: Since Perturbation theory is an advanced topic, I stopped at linear multivariable control and linear state estimation. Can you give me some clear material to read? Thanks!

Comment: Khalil, why Khalil? That book is a great boulder to read. :/

Comment: Never said to read the book, I said that it had a chapter on singular perturbation analysis.